# How to handle multiple foreign keys in CouchDb document?

Tags: couchdb

Sample blog scenario.

There are three entities: Post, Comment and Author (of the comment)
I would like to receive a list of comments in format: Comment.Header Post.Header Author.Name

### Post

Id
Header
Text
...

### Author

Id
Name
...

### Comment

Id
Header
Text
PostId
AuthorId

It is trivial to do using SQL joins, but I have no idea how to do this in CouchDb without extra request to database per comment which is not viable at all.

Comment: Are the comments nested in the post document?

Comment: No, let's imagine for the sake of experiment, that they should be kept separately. I wonder if there is a pattern solution in CouchDb to the problem of multiple foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have these entities :

Post

```
{
  "_id": "bbd998617a479940eb536cc842000630",
  "_rev": "1-1145fee61f02ebb32d12f03c95f5597d",
  "Header": "Example Header",
  "type": "post"
}
```

Author

```
    {
  "_id": "bbd998617a479940eb536cc842002322",
  "_rev": "1-aab8fd1832046602fed1cad425a98c0f",
  "name": "Example Author",
  "type": "author"
    }
```

Comment

```
{
  "_id": "bbd998617a479940eb536cc84200280c",
  "_rev": "2-f311bd9ab26867f924a837b0c0f76954",
  "type": "comment",
  "post": "bbd998617a479940eb536cc842000630",
  "author": "bbd998617a479940eb536cc842002322",
  "text": "Comment Text Blah Blah Blah"
}
```

You can build an index that produces the result you want using this design document :

```
 {
      "_id": "_design/query",
      "_rev": "9-f441a082e47b2cb51c72d001d9b411e3",
      "views": {
        "query": {
          "map": function(doc) {
                if (doc.type && doc.type=="comment") {
                    emit([doc._id],{ "_id":doc._id});
                    emit([doc._id, "author"],{ "_id":doc.author});
                    emit([doc._id, "post"],{ "_id":doc.post});
                }
            }
        }
      }, "lists" : {
          "listname":function(head,req){FUNCTION_BODY}
      }
      "language": "javascript"
    }
```

First emit will return the comment document, second emit and third emit will return the author and the post respectively.

You can then use a reduce function to reduce the query result to the required fields only and finally format your result using a _list function if needed.

Example _list to get JSON output:

```
function (head, req) {
  var row; 
  var i=0;
  var comments=[];
  while(row = getRow()){

    var comment_index=Math.floor(i/3);

    if(i%3==0){
         comments[comment_index] = {};
        comments[comment_index]["comment_text"]= row.doc.text;
    }
    else if(i%3==1){
        comments[comment_index]["author_name"]= row.doc.name;
    }
    else if(i%3==2){
        comments[comment_index]["post_header"]= row.doc.Header;
    }
    i++;
  }
  send(JSON.stringify(comments));
}
```

Then call your view through (You must include include_docs) : http://HOST/DATABASE/_design/DESIGN/_list/LIST/VIEW?include_docs=true

Comment: @EugeneKr Do you need the reduce/_list functions syntax?

Comment: Thanks Fady, seems like we are on the right path. Please provide syntax for reduce/_list.

Comment: Thanks Fady, I understand idea behind this, however your code for list function is not working. I have fixed it.

Comment: function (head, req) {
  var row;
  var i = 0;
  var comments = [];
  while (true) {
    comments[i] = {}
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      row = getRow();
      if (!row) break;

      switch (j) {
        case 0:
          comments[i]["comment_text"] = row.doc.text;
          break
        case 1:
          comments[i]["author_name"] = row.doc.name;
          break
        case 2:
          comments[i]["post_header"] = row.doc.Header;
          break
      }
    }

    if (!row) break;
    ++i;
  }

  send(JSON.stringify(comments));
}

Comment: Please take a look and update your answer with fixed code provided (it is tested). Then I will accept the answer.

Comment: Even better solution: function (head, req) {
  var items = [];
  var item;
  while (row = getRow()) {
      switch (row.doc.type) {
        case 'comment':
          if (item) {
            items.push(item);
          }
          item = { comment_text: row.doc.text };
          break;
        case 'post':
          item.post_header = row.doc.header;
          break;
        case 'author':
          item.author_name = row.doc.name
          break;
      }
  }

  if (item) items.push(item)
  send(JSON.stringify(items));
}

Comment: Nice catch, replaced. There are many ways to iterate through result rows and many ways to produce the output.